# Suggested edit count on review tab show wrong count on FB.SO mini site

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, mini-site

Mini-sites (wrongly) show the [suggested edit count](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) of the whole site:
[image]

---

But when you [navigate to it](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), it doesn't show any, because its (correctly) filtered for the mini-site:

[image]

Comment: -1 for drop shadows. Too much effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subsites like [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) (i.e. *only* [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com)) now let you just review everything you can review on the main site.